# Got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while learning Spring framework

Tags: java, spring

I've been searching for the reason why it failed for a long time, but couldn't figure it out.

**The structure of files**

```
src
 |__com.learn.spring.beans.annotation
 |   |__Main.java
 |   |__TestObject.java
 |
 |__beans.annotation.xml
```

**Main.java**

```
package com.learn.spring.beans.annotation;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans-annotation.xml");
        TestObject to = (TestObject)ctx.getBean("testObject");
        System.out.println(to);
    }
}
```

**TestObject.java**

```
package com.learn.spring.beans.annotation;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TestObject {

}
```

**beans-annotation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.learn.spring.beans.annotation"></context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

I got the following error:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Sep 21, 2015 4:08:51 afternoon org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1a6c5a9e: startup date [Mon Sep 21 16:08:51 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 21, 2015 4:08:51 afternoon org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [beans-annotation.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [beans-annotation.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/TargetSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:604)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.learn.spring.beans.annotation.Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/TargetSource
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:154)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.registerComponents(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.TargetSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: If you're learning Spring, skip the outdated XML and hand configuration and just start with a ready-to-go template from start.spring.io.

Comment: looks similar to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690431/got-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-while-learning-spring-framework

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the following to your pom.xml (if using maven)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What if not using Maven ?

Comment: Download the JAR file from here https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.3.20/spring-aop-5.3.20.jar and copy it to the below path /springIOC/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 8):

As you can see in the stacktrace the error is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.TargetSource`.

That means, that you miss the spring-aop.jar in your classpath.

Add it as a dependecy to your pom.xml if you work with maven. If not you have to add it and all the dependencies manually to your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

You could download required jar from [Maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.0.0.RELEASE). and add the same in your classpath. I hope it will work fine.